# Need to configure IIS for multiple clients. All of them will use a single code base but different application pools and databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, iis

I have a requirement to configure IIS for more than one client that will use a single codebase but different application pools and databases. For example, let's assume that the base URL of my website is https://www.mywebsite.com/ and I have five clients Client1, Client2, Client3, Client4, Client5. So the URLs should be the following: https://www.mywebsite.com/Client1, https://www.mywebsite.com/Client2, https://www.mywebsite.com/Client3, https://www.mywebsite.com/Client4, https://www.mywebsite.com/Client5, and every client must have its own application pool and database but they should use the same codebase.

Is there a possibility to configure IIS based on the above requirement?

Comment: It is feasible to set up every website for every user, as well as database deployment. However, it costs too much work. Also, you might alter your plan at any time.
Standing on this point, Docker indeed is a good idea. Package each system into an Image with encapsulating the web application and database deployment. Moreover, each application instance working only requires to make the container start to work. Of course, this requires lots of hardware resources.
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll definitely try docker.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to create an image from your codebase and use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) to solve your problem.
You can move all of your database settings to config file and change them easily for each image.

Here is a tutorial of working with docker:
https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll definitely try that.